# unitization of a Banach algebra

Tags: functional-analysis

For any algebra $A$, the linear
space $A_{1}=A+C=\{(a, k)|a \in A, k \in C\}$ equipped with the
multiplication $(a,k)(b, l) = (ab+kb+la, kl)$, so-called the unitization
of $A$, is a unital algebra with identity $(0, 1)$. How it includes $A$ as 
a two-sided ideal?

Answer (score 1):

We mean that A'= {(a,0):a in A} is an ideal and that is straightforward 
(a,k)(a',0)=(aa'+a0+0k,k0)=(aa',0) belongs to A'. Similarly (a',0)(a.k) belongs to A' for all (a,k) and (a',0).

Comment: Thanks, but why its codimension is one.